# parsing a file with a column of key/value pairs

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, key-value

I am trying to parse a tab delimited file with the last column has a variable number of key-value pairs separated by semicolon. Here is an example

```
ab cd ef as=2;sd=5;df=12.3
gh ij kl sd=23;df=55
mn op qr as=24;df=77
```

I want to print the 2nd column and the value associated with the key "sd"
The expected output should be

```
cd 5
ij 23
```

Can I do this in bash?

The problem here is that the key-value column has variable no of entries so that the target key will have different positions in different rows.

I can grep the values of a given key like this

```
grep -o 'sd=[^;]*' file.txt
```

but I can not print the other column values at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v k="sd=" '{n=split($NF,a,";");
                   for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                       if(a[i]~k) 
                          {sub(k,$2" ",a[i]);
                           print a[i]}}' file    

cd 5
ij 23
```

if your key is not fixed length anchoring it on the left is a better idea.
Change `a[i]~k` to `a[i]~"^"k`

Comment: just perfect. Thank you

Comment: WARNING: the original requirement seems to be that the key be equal to "sd"; if that is the requirement, then using `a[i]~k` might be asking for trouble.

Comment: I'm not seeing the anchoring (it's missing from both the `if` and the `sub`) and if $2 ever contained an `&` or `\<digit>` you would get a surprise in your output. I would not recommend doing it this way but YMMV depending on your input data.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have name/value pairs in your data it's best to create a name/value array from that data so you can just reference the values by name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete n2v
    split($NF,tmp,/[;=]/)
    for (i=1;i in tmp;i+=2) {
        n2v[tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
    }
}
"sd" in n2v { print $2, n2v["sd"] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
cd 5
ij 23
```

Comment: Would it be better to have `/sd/` at the top so the looping and splitting only happens if 'sd' is present?

Comment: That would add an operation for every line read so while it would make the processing a bit faster for lines that don't have `sd`, it could make the overall execution time slower depending on how many lines do contain `sd`. It'd also make the code harder to enhance and maintain in future if/when you want to add additional sub-fields to be printed. So, like most attempts at performance improvement, it's best left for consideration if/when you find you have a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for awk, but here is the obligatory sed one liner, that is a bit shorter than the awk examples. After peaks hint, I added a few more test cases with `sd` in different parts of the line.

```
cat kv.txt
ab cd ef as=2;sd=5;df=12.3
gh ij kl sd=23;df=55

test1 sd in col2=true;df=55
test2 sd_inFront spacer sd=2;other=5;
test3 sd_inMiddle spacer other1=6;sd=3;other2=8
test4 sd_atEnd spacer other1=7;sd=4;
test5 sd_AtEndWO; spacer other1=8;sd=5

test6 esd in col4=true;esd=6;
test7 esd_inFront spacer esd=7;other=5;
test8 esd_inMiddle spacer other1=6;esd=8;other2=8
test9 esd_atEnd spacer other1=7;esd=9;
test10 esd_AtEndWO; spacer other1=8;esd=10

test11 sd_and_esd spacer other1=6;sd=11;other2;esd=4;other3=8
test12 esd_and_sd spacer other1=6;esd=3;other2;sd=12;other3=8 

cat kv.txt| sed -nr "/(.+\w){3} (.*;)?sd=/ {s/.* (.*) .* (.*;)?sd=([^;]+).*/\1 \3/g; p;}"
cd 5
ij 23
sd_inFront 2
sd_atEnd 4
sd_AtEndWO; 5
sd_and_esd 11
esd_and_sd 12
```

The sed command consists of two parts: the first part `/(.+\w){3} (.*;)?sd=/` matches lines with `sd=` in coloumn four (either as first key or after a `.*;`) and applies the following part inside the braces to the line.

The second part inside the braces consists of a *substitution* (`s`) and a *print the result command* (`p`). The substitutions works like this:

- the four `.*` are your columns, the second column is captured with the parentheses
- `(.*;)?sd=([^;]+)` captures the values after `sd=` up to the `;`
- the replacement uses the captured `\1` (column two) and `\3` (the value after `sd=`) to create your desired output

Comment: WARNING: the original requirement seems to be that the key be equal to "sd"; if that is the requirement, then this proposed solution is not robust.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/file.txt
ab  cd  ef  as=2;sd=5;df=12.3
gh  ij  kl  sd=23;df=55
mn  op  qr  as=24;df=77
mn  sd  qr  as=24;df=77
```

(Those are tabs, not spaces)

You can set `awk` to separate fields on either a tab or a `;` like so:

```
$ awk -F "\t|;" '/sd/ {print $2}' /tmp/file.txt
cd
ij
sd
```

(I realize the last one should not be printed; bear with me)

To then print the field that has 'sd', simply loop through the fields:

```
$ awk -F "\t|;" '/sd/ { for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) if ($x~"^sd=") print $2 " " $(x) }' /tmp/file.txt
cd sd=5
ij sd=23
```

You can then split that field on `=`, change `$x~"^sd="` for an exact match, and print the field to the right of the split on either side of `=` to get your precise output:

```
$ awk -F "\t|;" '/sd/ { for (x=1;x<=NF;x++) if ($x~"^sd=") { split($x, tmp, /=/); print $2 " " tmp[2]}}' /tmp/file.txt
cd 5
ij 23
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great

Comment: WARNING: the original requirement seems to be that the key be equal to "sd"; if that is the requirement, then using `$x == "sd"` would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are gawk/awk solutions that avoid splitting and looping.

```
$ cat pf.txt
ab cd ef as=2;sd=5;df=12.3
gh ij kl sd=23;df=55
aa bb cc as=24;df=77;sd=15
mn op qr as=24;df=77
```

With gawk you can use a gensub capture group to isolate the desired value from `$4`:

```
$ gawk '/sd=/{print $2, gensub(/.*sd=([^;]*).*/,"\\1","g",$4)}' pf.txt
cd 5
ij 23
bb 15
```

Or, with non-gawk awk you use two `sub` calls to remove the parts before and after the desired value:

```
$ awk '/sd=/{ sub(/.*sd=/, "", $4); sub(/;.*/, "", $4); print $2, $4 }' pf.txt
cd 5
ij 23
bb 15
```

Comment: That would fail if his data contained something like `...sd=3;bsd=7...` though. You could anchor the front of the `sd` as, e.g., `.*[[:space:];]sd=` (or use `\<` in gawk) to fix that.